# Why am I getting these syntax errors?

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax-error

I have the following code

```
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int randInt = new Random().nextDouble() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2;

        if (randInt.equals(1)) {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isFirstImage) {       
                    applyRotation(0, 90);
                    applyRotation(0, 90);
                    isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

                } else {    
                    applyRotation(0, -90);
                    applyRotation(0, -90);
                    isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
                }
            }
        } else if (randInt.equals(2)) {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isFirstImage) {       
                    applyRotation(0, 90);
                    applyRotation(0, 90);
                    applyRotation(0, 90);

                    isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

                } else {    
                    applyRotation(0, -90);
                    applyRotation(0, -90);
                    applyRotation(0, -90);
                    isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

I have a "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement" on the line where I declare my integer, when I clearly do have a ";" there.
I have a few "Syntax error on token "(",:expected" and "Syntax error on token ")",;expected" where I have "public void onClick(View view) {" 
I have a "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement" but I looked everywhere and it seems I have closed all my statements.

I think Eclipse is giving me false errors, and I tried Project > Clean, but that didn't solve it. Please help, thanks!

Comment: you cannot call `.equals` on an int. just use `==`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the missing ";" error is spurious. Your real problem is how you are trying to declare the onClick listeners. The `if` blocks cannot contain method declarations like that. Try the following:

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    int randInt = new Random().nextDouble() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (randInt == 1) {
            if (isFirstImage) {       
                applyRotation(0, 90);
                applyRotation(0, 90);
            } else {    
                applyRotation(0, -90);
                applyRotation(0, -90);
            }
        } else if (randInt == 2) {
            if (isFirstImage) {       
                applyRotation(0, 90);
                applyRotation(0, 90);
                applyRotation(0, 90);
            } else {    
                applyRotation(0, -90);
                applyRotation(0, -90);
                applyRotation(0, -90);
            }
        }
        isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
    }
});
```

This will fix `randInt` at the time the `OnClickListener` is attached to `image1`. If you want a random rotation each time `image1` is clicked, move the declaration of `randInt` to be the first statement of the `onClick` method itself.

Comment: he probably wants to call `nextDouble()` inside each `onClick()`, otherwise the same `randInt` will be used for every click right?

Comment: @StevenByle - Good point; I'll add it to my answer. I don't know what OP actually wants to accomplish.

Comment: If the number is 1, I want it to rotate twice, but if the number is 2, I want it to rotate three times, it's not really working though; the image is only flipping once even though I'm calling the "applyRotation(0,90)" twice.

Comment: @MostafaSaadat - What does `applyRotation` do? (By the way, rotating by 90 three times is the same as rotating by -90 once, and vice versa.) The issue of where to declare `randInt` (as a field of the anonymous `OnClickListener` class or as a local variable of the `onClick` method) depends on whether you want the behavior to be the same on every click (use a field) or whether you want each click to be independently random (use a local variable).